# Catch an error without failing the Protractor test (wait for element to be visible)

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, protractor, try-catch

My application has a Terms and Conditions modal that only appears under certain circumstances. I would like the Protractor test to click Agree if the modal appears, and do nothing if it doesn't appear.

Here is my method, I try to wait for the element to appear, and catch the error if it doesn't appear. If the button appears, it is clicked and the test passes. However, if the button does not appear, the test fails with the "Element is taking too long..." message.

```
  waitForAgree() {
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    try {
      browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(this.agreeTerms), 5000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
      this.agreeTerms.click();
      this.continue.click();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("not found");
    }
  }
```

I have also tried the following. This gives me the message `Failed: Cannot read property 'agreeTerms' of undefined`

```
  clickAgree() {
    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    this.agreeTerms.isPresent().then(function (isPresent) {
      if (isPresent) {
        this.agreeTerms.click();
        this.continue.click();
      }
      else {
        console.log("not found");
      }
    })
  }
```

Any help on either of these errors is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to elaborate why your first method didn't work, we should note that using `Promise` and not be calling `.catch` is usually a bad idea because most of the time we will never know what was wrong and `try/catch` won't help at all. And this is also the reason that your *alternate method* succeded because you are calling `.catch` on the `Promise`.

If you are interested in making your first approach work, then you should be using `async/await`, something like this:

```
async waitForAgree() {
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    try {
      await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(this.agreeTerms), 5000, '...too long...');
      this.agreeTerms.click();
      this.continue.click();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("not found");
    }
}
```

Note the keyword `async` in front of the function name and `await` in front of the call to `browser.wait`. Note this is an `ES6` feature.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would store that **web element** in a **list** and if the `size of list` is equal to **1** (in this case I know button is present, so click it). If that list returns zero than print the fail message.

I will use **findElements** instead of **findElement**.

This is how you can defined the list :

```
var elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your locator"));
```

For calculating the size, you can use this :

```
var keys = Object.keys(elems);
var len = keys.length
```

and after that :

```
if (len == 1){
    this.agreeTerms.click();
    this.continue.click();
}
else{
  Do something here, button did not appear.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried an alternate method to my first one, and it works. I'm not entirely sure why the first one in my question fails, and this succeeds. If anyone would like to elaborate, thank you ahead of time. If you just need a working method, here:

```
  waitForAgree() {
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(this.agreeTerms), 5000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM')
    .then(() => {
      this.agreeTerms.click();
      this.continue.click();
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.log("not found");
    });
  }
```